WORKDIR command location in ContainerFile is affecting results
I'm doing some work training videos on podman and Containerfile, and I face something I don't understand.
This is the containerfile used by the solution:
FROM registry.example.com:8443/training/certificate-generator as certs

RUN ./gen_certificates.sh

FROM registry.example.com:8443/ubi8/nodejs-16:1
USER root
RUN groupadd -r student && useradd -r -m -g student student && \
    npm config set cache /tmp/.npm --global

COPY --from=certs --chown=student:student /app/*.pem /etc/pki/tls/private/certs/
COPY --chown=student:student . /app/

ENV TLS_PORT=8443 \
    HTTP_PORT=8080 \
    CERTS_PATH="/etc/pki/tls/private/certs"

WORKDIR /app

USER student

RUN npm install --omit=dev

But when I tried to create the Containerfile just looking at the instructions of the dry-exam I placed the WORKDIR command earlier in the file:
FROM registry.example.com:8443/training/certificate-generator as certs

RUN ./gen_certificates.sh

FROM registry.example.com:8443/ubi8/nodejs-16:1
USER root
RUN groupadd -r student && useradd -r -m -g student student && \
    npm config set cache /tmp/.npm --global

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=certs --chown=student:student /app/*.pem /etc/pki/tls/private/certs/
COPY --chown=student:student . /app/

ENV TLS_PORT=8443 \
    HTTP_PORT=8080 \
    CERTS_PATH="/etc/pki/tls/private/certs"

USER student

RUN npm install --omit=dev

And this Containerfile does not work. I get a permission denied error:
[..]
[2/2] STEP 9/9: RUN npm install --omit=dev
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/app/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
[..]

I just can't seem to understand why the location of the WORKDIR affects the permission, especially if I'm not referring to the relative paths.
I've also discovered the following:

Using both the WORKDIR commands before and after the COPY commands fails with same error
Using the WORKDIR between the COPY commands also works. Which leads me to the conclusion that the COPY with the --from is somehow affecting the result.

Why is this happening?

Finally found the issue after adding some RUN stat /app in key places!
Bottom line:
The command WORKDIR /app before the 2nd COPY command, creates the /app directory with root ownership. And therefore, the npm install command fails as it is run with student user.
If running the COPY command first, it creates both /app and all its sub-dir with the student ownership.
